# Куда поставить Qt, QtCreator и компиляторы чтобы проекты быстрее собирались?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, mingw, компилятор

Всем доброго времени суток!

У меня на ноутбуке есть всего 128 ГБ памяти на SSD. Собственно имеется внешний жесткий диск WD объемом 1ТБ, на который я установил QtCreator. Там же лежат Qt 5.15, MinGW и MSVC. Все вместе это занимает примерно 50 ГБ.

Проблема заключается в том, что большие проекты, над которыми я начал работать, собираются достаточно долго. Примерно 20-30 минут на 4 потоках (Процессор i3-7100U). Каждый раз тратить на это так много времени мне не хочется. Я думаю, что причина проблемы в нахождении QtCreator, Qt и компиляторов на внешнем жестком диске.

Мне не хотелось бы переустанавливать все это на системный диск. В связи с этим появляется вопрос, добьюсь ли я ускорения сборки, если переустановлю все это на системный SSD? Или может есть возможность увеличить скорость компиляции, если переустановить только некоторые компоненты? Также рассматриваю вопрос с приобретением внешнего SSD и подключению его к ноутбуку через Type-C.

Заранее благодарю за ваши ответы.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал для начала перенести свой проект и каталог сборки на SSD, если будет все еще недостаточно быстро, тогда уже думать как перенести остальное.

Comment: @Александр, проект и каталог сборки находятся на SSD.

Comment: я бы для начала посмотрел в лог компиляции, что бы понять, где оно тупит. Может там шаблон на шаблоне сидит макросом погоняет.

Comment: А вы не запускайте каждый раз полную пересборку, тогда компиляция будет существенно быстрее. А если все же каждый раз полной пересборки не происходит, то см предыдущий комментарий

Comment: Если оперативы мало, то память будет сбрасываться на ж.диск. SSD конечно шустрая вещь, но даже если и ее суммарно не хватит, то будете ждать долго